# Unable to execute task using ExecutorService in static workflow/block

Tags: java, future, executorservice, forkjoinpool

I am working on a module where a one-time cache is loaded using the `static` workflow. Cache loading usually takes around an hour. To improve the performance I am thinking about running these tasks in parallel using a thread pool. Here is the sample code. 

Application Startup class:

```
public class AppStart {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cache.isValid();  // this will trigger the static workflow
        // ...
    }
}
```

Cache loader class:

```
public class Cache {

    static {
        System.out.println("Static block initialization started!");
        initialize();
        System.out.println("Static block initialization finished!");
    }

    public static void initialize( ) {
        System.out.println("initialize() started!");
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(); // will replace with fixedThreadPool
        Future<String> future = executorService.submit(() -> "Hello world!");
        System.out.println("Retrieve the result of the future");
        String result = null;
        try {
            result = future.get();
            System.out.println(result);
        } catch( InterruptedException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch( ExecutionException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        executorService.shutdown();
    }

    public static boolean isValid( ) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

However, in the above case blocking operation `future.get` is getting blocked forever, even though it does nothing but a trivial task to return a String.

I also tried using `ForkJoinPool`, I had no luck.

I monitored threads using `jconsole` could not detect any deadlock. why is it behaving weirdly?

Comment: I would like to see the explanation on why it fails. But blocking the initialization of a class is a bad idea anyway. Remove the static block, and call initialize() explicitly in main().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be the expected behavior. this is a classic class initialization deadlock.

> a new Thread is started using the Runnable that is dependent on the completion of static initialization of a class. The class is, in turn, waiting for the Runnable to finish because of the `future.get()` method call.
>   The static initialization is waiting for thread to complete and thread is waiting for static initialization to complete.

[JLS:: Class initialiization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2) gives details on the class initialization process.

I wonder why `jconsole` couldn't detect the deadlock

Answer (score 0):

The static initializer for your `Cache` class doesn't complete – it's waiting on the completion of `future.get()`. You could remove the `static` initializer and call your method directly – `Cache.initialize()` – from `main()` or somewhere else, but whatever thread does that is going to be similarly blocked.

I suggest you create a separate thread to call `initialize()`, thus avoiding the blocking behavior, like this:

```
new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        initialize();
    }
}.run();
```

Comment: I know it is waiting for `future.get()` but why it is waiting for so long, submitted task is very lightweight.